# ARM template throws incorrect segments lengths for array of storage containers types

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I am getting `` Template validation failed: The template resource 'reports' for type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Common.Entities.TemplateGenericProperty`1[System.String]' at line '34' and column '79' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details. `` when I make ARM to create containers from the array in parameters file.

Issue line: `"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",`

Here is my ARM `template` file.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the storage account"
            }
        },
        "storageContaners": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the blob containers"
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storageContaners')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "Blob"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Here is my ARM `parameters` file.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "mystorageaccount"
        },
        "storageContaners": {
            "value":  "reports"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing `name` to different types but no luck. 
Can anybody please help me to figure it out the cause?

Answer (score 2):

The `name` parameters under the nested resources must be *one level* less than the `type`. 
Here `type` has **4** level(separated by 3 `/` ). 
 So `name` must have **3** level (separated by 2 `/`). 
`"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",` 
`"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('storageContaners')]",`

This applies when having nested resources under parent resource.